# CSP: How to debug violation: eval: "script-sample: var KERNEL = ..."

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, content-security-policy

We have a web service which has pretty strict CSP header that blocks `eval` among other things. We get many CSP violation reports that include following info:

```
{
  "csp-report": {
    "blocked-uri": "eval",
    "column-number": 61,
    "document-uri": "https://example.com/path/to/something",
    "line-number": 56,
    "original-policy": "default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; script-src 'self' 'report-sample' https://www.google-analytics.com; sandbox allow-downloads allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-presentation; img-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: about:; media-src *; frame-src * data:; report-uri https://example.com/:reportcspviolation",
    "referrer": "",
    "script-sample": "var KERNEL = $2C6A44CB_AD42_4731_A544_3F…",
    "source-file": "blob:https://example.com/b402b32e-ebf5-4103-b8e8-4cd3c1f56e2a",
    "violated-directive": "script-src"
  }
}
```

and the document at `document-uri` doesn't have any inline JavaScript. And the whole service source code does not contain uppercase letters `KERNEL` so it cannot be emitted by our service. The document at `document-uri` also doesn't use any `<iframe>` elements so the error cannot be caused by any nested document either.

All reports seem to include exactly same letters `var KERNEL = $2C6A44CB_AD42_4731_A544_3F` (with Firefox adding ellipsis and Chrome ends the sample as-is).

I've seen similar CSP reports from following UA strings (in order of how often this happens):

- `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0`
- `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36`
- `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36`
- `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0`

so it seems clear that this is not about browser compatibility. I cannot reproduce the errors by using any of the browsers and loading the address pointed by `document-uri`.

At least 95% of all reported errors with `var KERNEL =` have been emitted by Firefox 85.0.

Why is the `source-file` in `blob:` scheme? Is this some well-known hack to run JavaScript code by some browser extension?

**My best guess is that this is caused by some badly made browser extension but is there any way to figure the actual cause?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All reports seem to include exactly same letters var KERNEL = $2C6A44CB_AD42_4731_A544_3F

Such the signature belongs to the [malicious browser plugin](https://csplite.com/csp/ext598/) and affiliated virus.

> Why is the source-file in blob: scheme?  Is this some well-known hack to run JavaScript code by some browser extension?

I do not know is this a well-known hack, but some weird thing is observed in browsers behaviour.
Your CSP does not allow `blob:` therefore `blob:https://example.com/b402b32e-ebf5-4103-b8e8-4cd3c1f56e2a` must be blocked and we should observe `"blocked-uri": "blob"`. But we see `"blocked-uri": "eval"`, this means `blob:https://example.com/b402b32e-ebf5-4103-b8e8-4cd3c1f56e2a` is executed, and eval in its line 56 is blocked.

Note: The script of browser plugin above [uses](https://csplite.com/csp/ext598/#eval) `eval()` func calls and it uses [`blob:-URL`](https://csplite.com/csp/ext598/#blob) in the code.
Yes, these should be blocked by your CSP, but blocking `eval` inside `blob` is a nonsense for CSP like `script-src 'self' 'report-sample' https://www.google-analytics.com`.

Comment: +50 Great answer! And nice catch about the nonsense for "eval" vs "blob". I'm not totally surprised that CSP violation reports are often off-a-bit because these still seem to give pointers about stuff to fix. It would be great if reports included something like `dom-modified-by-extension: 1` if browser addons or extensions are in use. I think that privacy prevents leaking about which extension touched the DOM.

Comment: I have only one explanation about nonsense for "eval" vs "blob" - browsers extensions found a way to inject `blob:-URLs` bypass CSP. This isn't a particular browser bug because both Chrome and Firefox behaves similarly. Many thanks for the very interesting observation that you shared with the community.